# Computer is slow all of a sudden

Tags: windows-7

The problem started all of a sudden this afternoon. System specs: Windows 7 ultimate, 8gb ram, AMD Phenom II X4 910 Processor

Here are the symptoms:

- My computer started getting really slow all of a sudden
- I rebooted and it started 'Checking file system' ... this got stuck at 54%
- I tried   to start computer in Safe Mode and it got stuck on disk.sys
- At one point I got a blue screen when starting it in Normal mode
- Right now I can start windows normally but after about 4 min it grinds to a halt. This has given me short windows of opportunity to backup my photos. Luckily most were backup and everything else was in Dropbox.

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like your hard drive is dying, the disk check could take HOURS to complete if the disk is damaged enough.  Having said all that, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The question is: What should I do next?

Comment: What do you want to do? If the disk is dying you can either try to fix it or back up. If you try to fix it you may risk losing all your files...

Comment: Thanks guys. It sounds like I'm going to back up what I can and buy a new hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your hard drive is dying, the disk check could take HOURS to complete if the disk/file system is damaged enough.

Let it finish, or better, check out using [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) instead of the Windows disk check. As well you also may want to consult the hard drive manufacturer's website for diagnostics utilities that will be able to detect and possible fix drive-level errors.

If this is above your head, take it to a shop. :)